# Testing for correctness under asynchronous exceptions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, exception, asynchronous, concurrency

I am trying to come up with tests for correct behavior under asynchronous exceptions. To make things concrete, consider the following example,

```
casMVar :: Eq a => MVar a -> a -> a -> IO Bool
casMVar m old new = do
  cur <- takeMVar m
  if cur == old
  then putMVar m new >> return True
  else putMVar m old >> return False
```

where the invariant is that `m` is not empty. I think that this invariant is violated under asynchronous exceptions, since such an exception might arrive in the `if` expression. On my machine it is however not exposed by throwing exceptions at a forked `casMVar` with increasing delays, like so,

```
values :: Maybe (List Bool)
values = action <$> killDelays
where
  killDelays = toDelays <$> [-100..100]
  toDelays :: Int -> (Int, Int)
  toDelays dt = if dt < 0 then (-dt, 0) else (0, dt)
  action :: (Int, Int) -> IO (Maybe Bool)
  action (s, t) = do
    m <- newMVar False
    threadId <- forkIO $ threadDelay s >> void (casMVar m False True)
    threadDelay t
    throwTo threadId ThreadKilled
    tryReadMVar m
```

Although `values` is a list of `Just False`'s concatenated with a list of `Just True`'s.

Is there some way to expose the violation? Or at least to increase the probability that on a *some* machine the violation is exposed? I am specifically not looking for ways to make this code correct, the question is purely about testing.

Comment: Interesting. I would try adding a few `yield`s in the code do be tested so to suggest/force a thread switch.

Comment: A `yield` just before the `if` statement exposes the violation, sometimes.

Comment: You can increase the probability inserting `threadDelay` as needed.

Comment: That works for sure. But I would prefer not to touch the code under test.

Comment: You can probably make a monad that performs `yield` in `>>=`. But in general exception safety is hard to test, it is much easier to reason about it formally. In your example exception safety of `casMVar` depends on whether async exceptions are masked when it is executed.

Comment: You can also write your own `MVar` library which inserts delays/yields. In general, IMO, concurrency and tests do not mix well.

Comment: The tests are part of a suite of exercises I am making while reading Marlow's Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell. So the implementations are meant to be written by someone that is learning how to formally reason about concurrency.

Comment: I like your suggestion @Yuras. That works quite smoothly and only requires a minor modification of the return type of the IO functions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a general method for testing arbitrary code under asynchronous exceptions. For the particular example you gave, I would simply pass an exception throwing value as parameter of `casMVar`, and check whether after the evaluation of `casMVar` the `MVar` is non-empty:

```
boom = error "Handle me!"

pokemonHandler :: a -> SomeException -> IO a
pokemonHandler a e = return a

spec :: Spec
spec = do
  describe "casMVar" $ do
    it "puts back a value on the MVar under an exception" $ do
      m <- newMVar "foo"
      a <- async $
        casMVar m boom "bar" `catch` pokemonHandler True
      _ <- wait a
      val <- readMVar m
      val `shouldBe` "foo"
```

The complete code can be found here https://github.com/capitanbatata/sandbox/tree/master/testing-under-async-exceptions